# javascript to filter json and return another value

Tags: javascript, json

I have some javascript:

datasetID is set from the url value.

I get the json data.

```
  const datasetID = urlParams.get('datasetID')

  var data;
  $.getJSON("json/data.json", function(json){
    data = json;
  });
```

Next I want to filter the json data based on the datasetID, then retrieve the value assigned to another attribute `vernacularName` and assign it to a const.

```
  const record = data.filter(d => d.datasetID === datasetID);
  const vernacularName =
```

How far away am I? Suggestions welcome.

sample code

```
[
 {
  "datasetID":"A1"
  "language":"en",
  "accessRights":"CC BY 4.0",
  "vernacularName":"goat"
 }
]
```

Comment: without a clue what the data looks like, maybe `const vernacularName = filename[0].vernacularName`?? or, perhaps you want array `find` instead if there's only going to be at most one record that matches the condition ... then it'd be `const vernacularName = filename.vernacularName`

Comment: added some sample code for the data

Comment: and datasetID is a unique identifier so one 1 record will be returned

Comment: renamed `filename` to `record` so it makes more sense

Comment: well ... the comment stands `const vernacularName = record[0].vernacularName` - unless you use array `find`, then it'll be `const vernacularName = record.vernacularName`

Comment: the data.filter doesn't seem to work

Comment: why? do you get zero results? is there an error? do you know if `const datasetID = urlParams.get('datasetID')` matches any of the `datasetID` in the response? "doesn't seem to work" provides no information as to what the problem *may* be

Comment: was just troubleshooting, the filter works... ah was a trypo, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Filter in front-end is not a good option (let say your `data.json` is large) so if you could filter it in back-end before retrieving. For example, I send an ajax request with parameter `ID: datasetID` :

```
  const datasetID = urlParams.get('datasetID')

  var data;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/getjson",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (json) {
        record = json
        if (record.length === 1)
            vernacularName = record[0]["vernacularName"]
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('error');
    },
    data: {
        ID: datasetID
    },
    cache: false
  })
```

If you can't tweak in back-end and datasetID is unique then this should be enough:

```
if (record.length === 1)
            vernacularName = record[0]["vernacularName"]
```